# Stored procedure that insert a row and get the id of it and insert that id into another table

Tags: stored-procedures

I have a table `user` with columns

```
Id | Name | Email
```

I have another table `employee` with columns

```
Id | UserId | Designation
```

Is there a way to write a stored procedure where I insert a row into `User` and get the `Id`, and then use that `Id` (as `UserId`) to insert a row into the `Employee` table?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Learn to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For MySQL there's a function, [LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), you can check if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: its sql stored procedure. edited.

Comment: So you don't know which DBMS you are using?

Comment: No i know it. But its a wrong tag. Sorry for that

Comment: Oh good. Glad you know. If you want help you might want to tell us.

Comment: @SeanLange I am using SSMS 2014 and trying to write a stored procedure with the above-said requirement. I could not find the correct solution on web. Can you help me with that?

Comment: In SQL Server, `@@IDENTITY` will get you the identity value of the last inserted record, if the table has an identity key.

Comment: One option is to use OUTPUT. I would use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY though in case there are triggers on the table.

Comment: You could do the insert in a INSERT trigger on Table 1, and fetch the Id directly from the INSERTED virtual table.

Comment: You can also use the MERGE statement. @@IDENTITY isn't really thread safe and could get you the wrong value depending on how it's used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In data Insert script how to put parent record's id in child record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666689/in-data-insert-script-how-to-put-parent-records-id-in-child-record)

Answer (score 4):

Of course - no problem - try code something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUserAndEmployee 
    (@Name VARCHAR(100), 
     @Email VARCHAR(255), 
     @Designation VARCHAR(100)
    )
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Insert into "User"
    INSERT INTO dbo.User (Name, Email)
    VALUES (@Name, @Email);

    -- get the newly inserted ID
    DECLARE @UserId INT;
    SELECT @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Insert into "Employee"
    INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (UserId, Designation)
    VALUES (@UserId, @Designation);
END
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. if say i have table3 and want to insert id of employee into table3 then can i get that with 'DECLARE @@EmployeeId INT; SELECT @@EmployeeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY'

Comment: @adithyasai: yes, absolutely - but use just **one** `@` to denote a variable - `DECLARE @EmployeeId INT;` ...

Comment: I would suggest to wrap both inserts inside a transaction, and use `try..catch` with `rollback` on the `catch` for each insert.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: thanks, very good point - for production level code, this would be a must - this is just a simplified example to illustrate the basic mechanism, though .